# Using the ownership s in plural

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I think I never used the ownership "s" in plural. I want to use it now in this sentence but it look strange to me and I am not sure if I am using it correctly:

> to get z from one or both parties' values

Parties: (plural of party as in a communication party).

Comment: It's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the form absolutely right.

It's usually called "possessive" rather than "ownership": possession is a much wider concept than owning, and better suited to the uses of this form.